# How would one set up this differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have just started learning about differential equations, and I would like to know to set up this differential equation, and I would like to see if I am right.

QUESTION: The population of a certain mining town is known to increase at a rate proportional to itself. After 2 years the population doubled, and after 1 more year, the population was 10,000. What was the original population?

My solution: Denote $P(t)$ as the population of the town at year $t$. We then have $\frac{dP}{dt}$=$kP$, for some constant $k$. Then we have (switching signs and so forth), that $\frac{dP}{P}$=$k dt$. So integrating both sides yeilds $\log P$=$kt+C$. So raising both sides by $e$, we have $P$=$e^{kt+C}$=$C_1e^{kt}$. So we then have that at year $3$, the population is $10000$. In particular, $P(3)$=$10000$, and so solving for $k$ yields $k$=$\frac{\log 10000}{3}$. So this was the initial population.

But my dilemma is that this does not seem intuitive. $\frac{\log 10000}{3}$ is about $3$, which sounds quite absurd. So here are my final questions: Did I use the right method? Is my answer correct? If not correct, what would be the correct answer, and please show all possible details. (I am a beginner. Sorry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p(t)= c e^{k t}$$
$$p(3)=10000\to ce^{3k}=10000$$
$$p(2)=2p(0)\to  c e^{2k}=2c\to e^{2k}=2\to k=\frac{\ln 2}{2}$$

$$p(t)=c 2^{t/2}$$
$$p(3)=10000\to c 2^{3/2}=10000\to c=3536$$
so finally $$p(t)=3536\cdot 2^{t/2}$$
and we get $p(0)=3536$

Comment: You are right! Thank you for the correction @Semiclassical